# Can I create a SDL_Surface as I do with Allegro?

Tags: sdl

Using allegro I can create a Bitmap to draw just doing:

```
BITMAP* bmp = NULL;
bmp = create_bitmap(width,height); // I don't remember exactly the parameters
```

I'm using SDL now, and i want create an `SDL_Surface` to draw the game level (that is static). I create an `SDL_Surface`, draw the tiles on it, then just blit this surface to the screen instead of drawing the tiles directly on screen (I believe this will require more processing);

Is there a way to create a blank `SDL_Surface` as I did with Allegro to draw before I blit it?

Comment: If you care about searching on the sdl documentation, yes, there are.

Comment: Also, I'd check [Lazy Foo'](http://www.lazyfoo.net), as he does a lot of really good stuff regarding SDL, including Surface stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this function:

```
SDL_Surface* SDL_CreateRGBSurface(Uint32 flags, int width, int height, int bitsPerPixel,
             Uint32 Rmask, Uint32 Gmask, Uint32 Bmask, Uint32 Amask);
```

Check the docs to see what to pass as each argument.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you set up an

```
SDL_Surface * screen;
```

which is a pointer to a spot of memory that stores pixel information for a given resolution and color depth.  You create one as a screen initially and manage it with a SetVideoMode function.  You can then blit all of your images onto screen and flip the buffers at the end of your main loop.

You may also want to look into [SDL_Image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/) to make loading and working with various image files easier.  Also as someone else mentioned, I highly recommend [Lazy Foo's Tutorials](http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/).  There is information on his site about setting up and using SDL_Image.